# Paul Erdős and Ramanujan Primes

Tags: erdos, prime-numbers, reference-request

It's easy to find Ramanujan's proof of Ramanujan primes:

[Ramanujan's Proof](http://www.imsc.res.in/~rao/ramanujan/CamUnivCpapers/Cpaper24/page1.htm)

Wikipedia mentions that Paul Erdős also had a proof:

[Wikipedia article on Bertrand's Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_Postulate?#Erd.C5.91s.27s_theorems)

Does anyone know the full citation for Erdős's proof that for any number $n$, there exists a prime $p$ such that for all $x \ge p$, there are $n$ primes between $x$ and $2x$?

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question (as reference request). That said, does the Erdos paper cited in the references of that Wikipedia article do what you want?

Comment: The reference in Wikipedia (1934) does the full result with $n$ primes. The original paper on the Bertrand Postulate itself was in Acta. Litt. Ac. Sci. (Szeged) vol 5 (1932) pp 194-198. The 1932 article was responsible for: $$ $$
Chebyshev said it, and I say it again, $$ $$
There is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$

Comment: You may also want to check "Proofs from the book", where Erdős's original argument is presented (with a picture of the paper), together with a further simplification he suggested (with a picture of the note).

Comment: Will, thanks very much!

I found it in German:
http://www.math-inst.hu/~p_erdos/1932-01.pdf

And Google's translation to English:
http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math-inst.hu%2F~p_erdos%2F1932-01.pdf&sl=de&tl=en&hl=&ie=UTF-8


Comment: Andres, thanks for the reference to "Proofs from the book".  I own it and didn't realize that page 10 spoke about an estimate for the number of primes between n and 2n.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

I'm familiar with Betrand's Postulate but wasn't clear how it implied the existence of Ramanujan primes.

Comment: Yemon, thanks for your question.  Here's what the Wikipedia article says:

Erdős proved that for any positive integer k, there is a natural number N such that for all n > N, there are at least k primes between n and 2n. An equivalent statement had been proved earlier by Ramanujan (see Ramanujan prime).

Comment: Larry, my point was that the Wikipedia article has a list of references at the end, and it wasn't clear to me if you'd originally looked at those already.

Comment: Yemon, got it.  Sorry that I didn't understand.  

I should have mentioned that when I checked the Erdos paper on Schur and Sylvester, I did not find the details that I expected.

Here's the link I used to the Erdos paper that's cited in the Wikipedia article:
http://profs.sci.univr.it/~bellin/philsci/Erdos.pdf


Comment: You may enjoy reading Erdős's own recollections in "Ramanujan and I"


http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1989-29.pdf